# Axios post returning 404

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I am trying to send a post request with query params using axios (running in node.js), but its responding with `404`if its sent like this

```
let response = await axios.post(config.API_ENDPOINT, {
        params: {
            q: 'addLead',
            key: config.API_KEY,
            firstName: lead.firstName,
            workPhone: lead.workPhone,
            userName: lead.userName,
            projectName: lead.projectName
        }
    });
```

however it works if I form the query parameters through string like this (without params object):

```
let url = config.API_ENDPOINT + `?q=addLead&key=${config.API_KEY}&firstName=${lead.firstName}&workPhone=${lead.workPhone}&userName=${lead.userName}&projectName=${lead.projectName}`;
```

The former way being neat and secure I guess, I can't figure out what's wrong, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a post request, the second parameter is reserved for the body payload, the third parameter is where you sent the params.

```js
let response = await axios.post(config.API_ENDPOINT, null, {
        params: {
            q: 'addLead',
            key: config.API_KEY,
            firstName: lead.firstName,
            workPhone: lead.workPhone,
            userName: lead.userName,
            projectName: lead.projectName
        }
    });
```